# How to find the postion of a property which is holding some value in a List

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

//  Here i want to know the index of each property in a List Flux which is fetching the value from an excel because later i have to fetch the value of these properties from the List.The problem i am facing is that sometimes some properties are not having any value in a specified row during the execution so i am not able to fetch them in the form Flux[0].VMS,OnHold[0].VMS,Active[0].VMS etc. The index is ambiguous so i need to know the index of each property in a List which is having some value.

```
    List<Summary> Flux = new List<Summary>();//total influx of each property

                    if (str1 == "Influx" && str1 != "Grand Total")
                    {
                        for (rCnt = rCnt + 7; rCnt < range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
                        {
                            str = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, 1] as Excel.Range).Text;
                            if (str == "VMS")
                            {
                                Summary summary = new Summary();
                                summary.VMS = xlWorkSheet.Cells[rCnt, 5].Text;

                                Flux.Add(summary);

                            }
                            if (str == "eService")
                            {
                                Summary summary = new Summary();
                                summary.eService = xlWorkSheet.Cells[rCnt, 5].Text;

                                Flux.Add(summary);

                            }
                            if (str == "RES")
                            {
                                Summary summary = new Summary();
                                summary.Res = xlWorkSheet.Cells[rCnt, 5].Text;

                                Flux.Add(summary);
                            }
                            if (str == "RSC")
                            {
                                Summary summary = new Summary();
                                summary.RSC = xlWorkSheet.Cells[rCnt, 5].Text;

                                Flux.Add(summary);
                            }
                            if (str == "VFS")
                            {
                                Summary summary = new Summary();
                                summary.VFS = xlWorkSheet.Cells[rCnt, 5].Text;

                                Flux.Add(summary);
                            }
                            if (str == "SYS 80")
                            {
                                Summary summary = new Summary();
                                summary.System80 = xlWorkSheet.Cells[rCnt, 5].Text;

                                Flux.Add(summary);
                            }

                            if (str == "HCL")
                            {
                                Summary summary = new Summary();
                                summary.HCL = xlWorkSheet.Cells[rCnt, 5].Text;

                                Flux.Add(summary);
                            }
                            if (str == "Others")
                            {
                                Summary summary = new Summary();
                                summary.Others = xlWorkSheet.Cells[rCnt, 5].Text;

                                Flux.Add(summary);
                            }

                        }
                        break;
                    }

     //while fetching the vaues of each property having some value is the below code,instead of hardcoding the index of each property which has some value, i want to store it somewhere and then fetch it while writing the values in a cell.

 xlWorkSheet.Cells[iCount, jCount] = Flux[0].VMS;        //Daily influx
xlWorkSheet.Cells[iCount + 2, jCount] = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(OnHold[0].VMS)-Convert.ToInt32(xlWorkSheet.Cells[iCount+4,jCount-1].Text)); //Tickets moved to hold    
xlWorkSheet.Cells[iCount+3, jCount] = Active[0].VMS;     // Ending Backlog
xlWorkSheet.Cells[iCount + 4, jCount] = OnHold[0].VMS;   //Ending Hold
```

Comment: So you expect, for example, `Flux[0]` to *only* have `VMS` defined, and e.g., `Flux[1]` might *only* have `RSC` defined? And later on you need to know which index has `VMS` and which index has `RSC`?

Comment: yes you are absolutely right.

Comment: Do you also expect to have more than 1 `VMS` (or any property) defined? If you expect only 1 of each property, then get rid of your list and just do 1 `new Summary()`, and add each property to it. If you expect duplicates of a property, then how are you choosing which one to use?

Comment: During each execution only one property is assigned.How to know that at  execution which index is assigned to a property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you said that during execution only 1 property is assigned, my first thought is to just do the following. But this depends on how you fill in `Active` and `OnHold`; you should just change those to work like I made this one work:

```
Summary summary = new Summary();

                if (str1 == "Influx" && str1 != "Grand Total")
                {
                    for (rCnt = rCnt + 7; rCnt < range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
                    {
                        str = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, 1] as Excel.Range).Text;
                        if (str == "VMS")
                        {                                
                            summary.VMS = xlWorkSheet.Cells[rCnt, 5].Text;
                        }
                        if (str == "eService")
                        {
                            summary.eService = xlWorkSheet.Cells[rCnt, 5].Text;
                        }
                        if (str == "RES")
                        {
                            summary.Res = xlWorkSheet.Cells[rCnt, 5].Text;
                        }
                        if (str == "RSC")
                        {
                            summary.RSC = xlWorkSheet.Cells[rCnt, 5].Text;
                        }
                        if (str == "VFS")
                        {
                            summary.VFS = xlWorkSheet.Cells[rCnt, 5].Text;
                        }
                        if (str == "SYS 80")
                        {
                            summary.System80 = xlWorkSheet.Cells[rCnt, 5].Text;
                        }

                        if (str == "HCL")
                        {
                            summary.HCL = xlWorkSheet.Cells[rCnt, 5].Text;

                        }
                        if (str == "Others")
                        {
                            summary.Others = xlWorkSheet.Cells[rCnt, 5].Text;
                        }

                    }
                    break;
                }

 //while fetching the vaues of each property having some value is the below code,instead of hardcoding the index of each property which has some value, i want to store it somewhere and then fetch it while writing the values in a cell.

xlWorkSheet.Cells[iCount, jCount] = summary.VMS;        //Daily influx
xlWorkSheet.Cells[iCount + 2, jCount] = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(OnHold[0].VMS)-Convert.ToInt32(xlWorkSheet.Cells[iCount+4,jCount-1].Text)); //Tickets moved to hold    
xlWorkSheet.Cells[iCount+3, jCount] = Active[0].VMS;     // Ending Backlog
xlWorkSheet.Cells[iCount + 4, jCount] = OnHold[0].VMS;   //Ending Hold
```